# Editing the last line of a .txt file

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project which involves that every time I call a particular function `increment()`, I'd be editing the last line of a text file.

Example text file:

```
0 0
10 1
50 2
30 3
```

My goal would be every time I call `increment()`, the first token in the last line would increment by, for example, 10.  So calling the function once would yield:

```
0 0
10 1
50 2
40 3
```

Comment: Please try writing some code, then come back with a specific question about why that code didn't behave as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file and read it line by line by saving all of them into a List. Then you modify its last element and get the previous value to increment (30 in your example):

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) { //opening the file
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
       // process the line.
       lines.append(line);
    }
}

String lastLine = lines.remove(lines.size() - 1); 
lastLineTokens = lastLine.split(" ");

String result = String.parseInt(lastLineTokens.get(0)) + " " lastLineTokens.get(1);
lines.append(result); //here's the modified list
```